# sed: Conditional line deletion in one command

Tags: sed

Assume I have the following example text in `example.txt`:

```
<para>This is some paragraph text
This is another line of paragraph text.
</para>
```

What I want to achieve: Replace all `<para>` and `</para>` tags with the null string, if the resulting line is empty, delete the line. I achieved this with the following two commands:

```
# remove the line that solely consist of the para tag.
$ sed -i '/^<para>$/d;/^<\/para>$/d' ./example.txt

# Replace any of the para tags with an empty string.
$ sed -i 's/<para>//g;s/<\/para>//g' ./example.txt
```

My question: Is it possible to achieve this in one sed command, making use of a conditional line deletion?

Comment: Do you care if there are more ampty lines? If so, do you want to keep them?

Comment: @guillermochamorro I use GNU sed and I do want to keep the other empty lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, you could use the `T` command to branch past an empty line delete if the replacement fails:

```
sed 's/<\/\{0,1\}para>//g;T;/^$/d' example.txt
```

> ```
> T label
> ```
>
> Branch to label only if there have been no successful substitutions since the last input line was read or conditional branch
>   was taken. The label may be omitted, in which case the next cycle is
>   started.

With non-GNU sed it should be possible to do the same by combining `t` and `b`

```
sed -e 's/<\/\{0,1\}para>//g;ta;b' -e ':a;/^$/d' example.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -nE 's|</?para>||g;/./p' file
```

Perform the required substitution(s) and if after that you are left with something,   print it. OTW, your pattern space, aka current line, comprised only `para` and/or `/para` tags exclusively, and those records need to be suppressed.